# Swift 3 Core Data NSExpression Always Returning 0

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am trying to get the sum of a property of a managed object in Core Data, but it seems like no matter what I do I get 0.

The object I am trying to get the sum of the estimatedValue property on all of my Opportunity objects. The estimatedValue property is a decimal in Core Data.

Here is my current version of the code:

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Opportunity")
fetchRequest.resultType = .dictionaryResultType
fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

let expression = NSExpressionDescription()
expression.expression =  NSExpression(forFunction: "sum:", arguments:[NSExpression(forKeyPath: "estimatedValue")])
expression.name = "sumOfEstimatedValue";
expression.expressionResultType = .decimalAttributeType

fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = [expression];

do {
    let opportunityAggregates = try stack.context.fetch(fetchRequest)
    print(opportunityAggregates)
} catch {
    print("Failed to fetch aggregates")
}
```

The results of the above code is:

```
[{
    sumOfEstimatedValue = 0;
}]
```

Here is a print out of the opportunities saved in the app:

```
[<Opportunity: 0x60800009dd80> (entity: Opportunity; id: 0x60800002d8c0 <x-coredata:///Opportunity/tB6E74585-FDA0-4061-89CC-D89EEB25156C17> ; data: {
    company = nil;
    contact = "0x608000028d40 <x-coredata:///Contact/tB6E74585-FDA0-4061-89CC-D89EEB25156C2>";
    createdDate = "2017-09-03 22:40:00 +0000";
    estimatedValue = "42.41";
    opportunityDescription = nil;
    projectedCloseDate = nil;
    stage = "0x60800002d860 <x-coredata:///Stage/tB6E74585-FDA0-4061-89CC-D89EEB25156C16>";
}), <Opportunity: 0x60800009dc90> (entity: Opportunity; id: 0x60800002d380 <x-coredata:///Opportunity/tB6E74585-FDA0-4061-89CC-D89EEB25156C15> ; data: {
    company = nil;
    contact = "0x608000028d40 <x-coredata:///Contact/tB6E74585-FDA0-4061-89CC-D89EEB25156C2>";
    createdDate = "2017-09-03 22:40:00 +0000";
    estimatedValue = "42.41";
    opportunityDescription = nil;
    projectedCloseDate = nil;
    stage = "0x60800002d440 <x-coredata:///Stage/tB6E74585-FDA0-4061-89CC-D89EEB25156C14>";
}), <Opportunity: 0x60800009d9c0> (entity: Opportunity; id: 0x60800002b8e0 <x-coredata:///Opportunity/tB6E74585-FDA0-4061-89CC-D89EEB25156C9> ; data: {
    company = nil;
    contact = "0x608000028d40 <x-coredata:///Contact/tB6E74585-FDA0-4061-89CC-D89EEB25156C2>";
    createdDate = "2017-09-03 22:40:00 +0000";
    estimatedValue = "42.41";
    opportunityDescription = nil;
    projectedCloseDate = nil;
    stage = "0x60800002aaa0 <x-coredata:///Stage/tB6E74585-FDA0-4061-89CC-D89EEB25156C8>";
}), <Opportunity: 0x60800009dab0> (entity: Opportunity; id: 0x60800002c580 <x-coredata:///Opportunity/tB6E74585-FDA0-4061-89CC-D89EEB25156C11> ; data: {
    company = nil;
    contact = "0x608000028d40 <x-coredata:///Contact/tB6E74585-FDA0-4061-89CC-D89EEB25156C2>";
    createdDate = "2017-09-03 22:40:00 +0000";
    estimatedValue = "42.41";
    opportunityDescription = nil;
    projectedCloseDate = nil;
    stage = "0x60800002d3e0 <x-coredata:///Stage/tB6E74585-FDA0-4061-89CC-D89EEB25156C10>";
}), <Opportunity: 0x60800009dba0> (entity: Opportunity; id: 0x60800002d140 <x-coredata:///Opportunity/tB6E74585-FDA0-4061-89CC-D89EEB25156C13> ; data: {
    company = nil;
    contact = "0x608000028d40 <x-coredata:///Contact/tB6E74585-FDA0-4061-89CC-D89EEB25156C2>";
    createdDate = "2017-09-03 22:40:00 +0000";
    estimatedValue = "42.41";
    opportunityDescription = nil;
    projectedCloseDate = nil;
    stage = "0x60800002c140 <x-coredata:///Stage/tB6E74585-FDA0-4061-89CC-D89EEB25156C12>";
}), <Opportunity: 0x60800009d3d0> (entity: Opportunity; id: 0x60800002b3a0 <x-coredata:///Opportunity/tB6E74585-FDA0-4061-89CC-D89EEB25156C7> ; data: {
    company = nil;
    contact = "0x608000028d40 <x-coredata:///Contact/tB6E74585-FDA0-4061-89CC-D89EEB25156C2>";
    createdDate = "2017-09-03 22:40:00 +0000";
    estimatedValue = "42.41";
    opportunityDescription = nil;
    projectedCloseDate = nil;
    stage = "0x60800002abe0 <x-coredata:///Stage/tB6E74585-FDA0-4061-89CC-D89EEB25156C6>";
})]
```

Thank you for any help you may be able to provide.

Comment: Can you try commenting this line `fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = [expression];` and then please post the output what you are getting.

Comment: @ViniApp The 3rd code block that contains the print out of the Opportunities in the app is what I get when I do that. I got those results by commenting out that line and `fetchRequest.resultType = .dictionaryResultType`. I have no clue why the same fetchRequest returns everything, but returns incorrect results when used with an expression. I am new to iOS development so there might be something I am missing, but I think this looks like all the tutorials and examples I was looking at.

Comment: Is the core-data setup backed by a SQL store or an in-memory store?

Comment: @JonRose It is SQLite

Comment: From that output, it looks like `estimatedValue` is a string, which makes adding them up difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code in the original question is now working. I'm not quite sure what was wrong, but wiping the app data from my device and populating it with the exact same data fixed it.